# Finding stops in list of coordinates

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of points: {lat, lng, timestamp}. The list is created by server dumping position of a car every 5 seconds.

Having a list of for example 100000 points how to find stops that took for example not longer than 3 minutes?

Comment: Could you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: You can sort the points by their timestamps in non-decreasing order. Then compress the resulting list in a way that every elements becomes this :

(lat, lng, number_of_contigous_timestamps)

Then you only need to count stops that timestamp counter is lower than 36(36 * 5 is 3 minutes).

Comment: is this a real world problem where the `(lat,lon)` pairs are acquired by a GPS device (and thus slightly imprecise, e.g. even though the car has stopped for 1 minute you get 12 slightly different positions) or just an exercise problem?